# PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException Access to undeclared static property: yii\filters\HttpCache::$cacheControlHeader

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to set this property, but it's failing.

Code (view):

```
        if (Yii::$app->user->identity && Yii::$app->user->identity->admin):
          \yii\filters\HttpCache::$cacheControlHeader = 'no-cache'; // prevent Fastly from caching admin links
```

Docs: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-http.html#cache-control

Yii 2.0.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That property [isn't a static property](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/filters/HttpCache.php#L92).

To set the cache control header, you'll need to add that class as a controller filter and set to property there. Something like this should work (YMMV with respect to extending controllers/behavior definitions):

```
public function behaviors() {
    return array(
        array(
            "class" => "yii\filters\HttpCache",
            "cacheControlHeader" => Yii::$app->user->identity && Yii::$app->user->identity->admin ? 
                "no-cache" : "public, max-age=3600",
        ),
    );
}
```

Comment: Wow really? What if I have that partial in many pages, and it uses many controllers? I have to add that to each & every controller?

Comment: Ideally you'd have a main controller that all others (or those that you want to contain this functionality) extend from